# How can I enable the Front Page on minimal profile?

Tags: 8

I installed D8 using the minimal profile but it does not have or does not enable the front page view, redirecting requests to the user page. How can I enable the standard front page (with the recent posts)?

Comment: The "Frontpage" view is created automatically upon installation. Did you set the `/node` page as the default front page in: Admin -> Configuration -> Site information?

Comment: I think that is clear, frontpage (with the recent posts) is a 'View' and minimal profile don't install it, then, no frontpage with 'views' page and blocks. Check on `core/profiles/minimal/minimal.info.yml` in the `dependencies` which modules are installed.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. So, to document the solution:

1. Enable Views and Views UI modules
2. Either set the Front Page to the now-available `frontpage` for the traditional recent posts page

Another way (which was more suited to my intents) is to create a new content type (e.g. Static Page), create a new node of that type and set the site frontpage to that. This is useful when you are developing a theme with a custom frontpage template featuring several regions to be filled with different views.